# collect only relevant links from url

Tags: java, solr, web-crawler, crawler4j

What I need is to collect the relevant links from the `url`. For example from a link like http://beechplane.wordpress.com/ , i need to collect the links that contains the actual articles. ie, links like http://beechplane.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/the-95-confidence-of-nate-silver/ , http://beechplane.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/visualizing-probability-roulette/ etc.

How can I get those links in Java? Is it possible using web-crawlers?

Answer (score 0):

I use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library for that.

How get all `<a>` tags from document:

```
Elements a = doc.select("a");
for (Element el : a) {
    //process element
    String href = el.attr("href");
}
```

Comment: but this method return all the hyperlinks in that page. what i need is the relevant links only

Comment: You can select links from inner element of document, what you need